# Strange execution of get accessor in c#?

Tags: c#, get

I set up a simple program just to test how the code inside a get accessor executes (since I had been having some issues in another project), and found something quite strange:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var test = new TestClass();
        var testBool = test.TestBool;
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    private bool _testBool = true;
    public bool TestBool {
        get {
            if (_testBool) {
                Console.WriteLine("true!");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("false! WTF!");
            }
            _testBool = false;
            return _testBool;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be

> true!

But what I got instead was

> true!
>
> false! WTF!

Just what is going on here?

Comment: Are you running the program in the debugger?  The debugger will call property getters behind your back.

Comment: Why did you re-ask this question after deleting it? The solution is probably the same "IDE executes the accessor because it expects it to have no side-effects" thing.

Comment: remove `test.TestBool` from the watch or run the application without debugging.

Comment: (merged with duplicate; please don't double-post - especially since two answers were already on the post you deleted)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Would have been three had he not deleted his post just before I submitted my answer. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048790/c-getter-property-is-run-without-anyone-calling-it

Comment: @Marc I deleted it because I thought I had made a mistake. But I couldn't undelete it, so I posted it again. I did not reload to see answers as I thought you guys wouldn't be so damn quick :P.

Comment: @Mark Sorry. I know losing what your wrote feels like crap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say that the *debugger* ran it once to show the members of a local variable in the IDE.

If you have side effects in properties (which you shouldn't), don't run it in the IDE :)

Try it at the console; it should behave itself there.

Comment: Holy cow, how did you answer this before it was asked?  Supermod question merging powers?

Comment: @Ben: The asker asked this question earlier, then deleted it, then asked it again. Marc merged the deleted question with this one.

Comment: +1 I can only reproduce it if I mouse over the TestBool property, which then causes the getter to be called.

Comment: Ayup, thanks for the tip. I needed to have that smacked into.

Comment: There's a point in just deleting the dup question instead of merging it.  I hit the wrong one :(

Answer (score 8):

No repro.

And don't write Getters with side effects.

Comment: +1 for "don't write properties with side effects" (because I can't do a +100!).

Comment: @Jason: Hank had it right -- it's only getters that should not have side effects, side effects in setters (e.g. property notify listener) are perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ben: I was agreeing with Henk. Of course *expected, intuitive* "side effects" in setters are ok. But programmers naturally expect properties to be *lightweight*, so *unexpected* side effects can be evil (for example: Set one property and the values of other seemingly unrelated properties change; Set a property and it doesn't return for 5 seconds while it redraws some UI, and commits the record to a database). Properties can be badly abused, and *very* difficult to debug, especially as *even the debugger assumes they are lightweight and single-steps over them as if they are simple variables*.